# Using apache .htaccess to rewrite "/" as ".html"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

To give a quick example of what I'm after, this is what I want:

```
example.com/folder/about/
```

Will show me the page located at:

```
example.com/folder/about.html
```

Currently, my .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder/$1\.html [NC,R=301,L]
```

Which works when I go to:

```
example.com/folder/about
```

But not when I go to:

```
example.com/folder/about/
```

Which tries to load:

```
example.com/folder/about.html/
```

Which is not a file or directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable for the second time, capturing the file name:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
#new line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html .*/(.*)/?
RewriteRule ^folder/ folder/%1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

### update

Put this before the previous block

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)/ folder/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: I can understand what you have done, and why it should work, but for some reason it still looks up "folder/about.html/", when I go to "folder/about/". +1 because it makes sense and should work, afaik.

Comment: @Exodia_the_403_forbidden_one Seems, that it keeps the slash in the variable. Looking, how to fix now.

Comment: @Exodia_the_403_forbidden_one Adding optional slash at the end helped me. Please, try.

Comment: Again, same problem, sorry to be a pain, I can see you're trying just as hard as I am to fix it.

Comment: @Exodia_the_403_forbidden_one Hm, it worked on my system. Are you using only these lines in your htaccess?

Comment: Yes, I'm just using this. Just checked my apache site settings to make sure I didn't have any rules in there.

Comment: @Exodia_the_403_forbidden_one If nothing more helps, you can try hard coding the rule with slash. Even though, it's an ugly solution. I edited the question.

Comment: I really want to accept it, but for some reason it isn't working on mine, I'll leave it open but if nobody else has anything to offer then I'll accept it, since it should work.

Comment: @Exodia_the_403_forbidden_one Maybe, it's one of the options? Try disabling all of them: `Options -All -MultiViews`

Comment: It didn't work, but I'm giving you the question, great support and I'm sure it would work on any server but mine.